# EMBERJS. Params.Param1 Undefined

Tags: ember.js

I have got this routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
// put your routes here

this.resource('about');
this.resource('querydefault');
this.resource('query', {path:':query_done'}, function() {
  this.route('time', {path:':time_interval'});
}); 
});
```

Transition from this #link-to

```
{{#link-to 'query.time' this '24' }}Time Interval{{/link-to}}
```

And when I try to retrieve the query_done is Undefined.

```
App.QueryTimeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:  function (params) {
   params.time_interval; (24) OK   
   params.query_done; UNDEFINED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Params are consumed by the resource that handles them. If you don't need `/query` resource for anything, you can do something like:

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('querydefault');
    this.resource('query', {path:''}, function() {
        this.route('time', {path:'/query/:query_done/time/:time_interval'});
    });
});
```

However, I believe the truly idiomatic solution would be to let the resource consume first param on its level and then pass it along to child resources / routes.

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('querydefault');
    this.resource('query', {path:'/query/:query_done'}, function() {
        this.route('time', {path:'/time/:time_interval'});
    });
});

App.QueryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:  function (params) {
        console.log("/Query query_done: " + params.query_done); // OK

        return {
            queryDone: params.query_done // pass it through here
        };
    }
});

App.QueryTimeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:  function (params) {
        console.log("QueryTime query_done: " + params.query_done);  // empty
        console.log("QueryTime time_interval: " + params.time_interval);  // OK
        console.log("From parent resource: " + this.modelFor("query").queryDone);  // retrieve it through here

        return {};
    }
});
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/seliz/1/edit).

Comment: Thank you! But I am returning and Ajax promise, how could I return also that parameter??    My current return:  return Ember.$.ajax(...then(function(data){
       return data.responseData.feed.entries.map(function(post){
        
        
        return post;  
       });
        });

Comment: You can attach it to the model, I guess. `...then(function (data) { var arr = data.responseData.feeds.map(/*...*/); arr.queryDone = params.query_done; return arr;})`. I'm not sure this is the best way, though. I'll think it through and if I figure out a better solution, I'll post another answer.